# SQL 5.6 Foreign key statement error

Tags: mysql

i am new to SQL and i am trying out some simple create table statement but i am facing some problem with the foreign key at EMPLOYEEGROUP table. Below is a part of my create table statement

```
   CREATE TABLE `User` (
`Userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Username` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
`Password` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Userid)
);

CREATE TABLE `Group` (
`GroupID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`GroupName` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (GroupID)
);

CREATE TABLE `EMPLOYEEGROUP` (
`EmployeeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`AssignedGrp` int(11) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEEGROUP_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES User (Userid),
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEEGROUP_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (AssignedGrp) REFERENCES Group (GroupID)
);
```

There is some issue with my EMPLOYEEGROUP_FK2 statement which i can't seem to solve it. any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql GROUP is a reserved keyword. and you used group as table name 
. but in table name you write group with `` . and when you take reference of group table you write group without ``. simple add `` in group name
Try blow query. it execute in my system hopfully execute also your system

```
  CREATE TABLE `User` (
`Userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Username` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
`Password` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Userid)
);

CREATE TABLE `Group` (
`GroupID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`GroupName` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (GroupID)
);

CREATE TABLE `EMPLOYEEGROUP` (
`EmployeeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`AssignedGrp` int(11) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEEGROUP_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES User (Userid),
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEEGROUP_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (AssignedGrp) REFERENCES `Group` (GroupID)
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I been trying this for the past few hour and it did not occur to me its the naming problem.